# Conditional probability, given probabilities of events

Tags: probability

A company has observed that $40$% of it's customers choose to buy service $A$. The probability that a customer buys service $B$ is $\frac{2}{7}$, and the probability that a customer does not buy service $A$ or $B$ is $\frac{3}{13}$. What is the probability that a customer orders service $B$ but not service $A$?

**Attempt;**

$P(A) = 0.4$

$P(B) = 2/7$

$1 - P(A \cup B) = \frac{3}{13}$

$P(A \cup B) = \frac{10}{13}$

Is my initial formulation correct? Can I use Baye's rule from here?

Comment: Just draw a Venn diagram, and fill in the probabilities.

Comment: Hint: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! What would happen if I changed the numbers to P(A) = 0.5, P(B) = 0.25, and the probability that a customer buys neither service  = 0.25. Would this mean that P(AnB) = 0?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Great! So for this case, the events A and B would be mutually exclusive as P(AnB) = 0, but they would not be independent, is that correct?

Comment: Right. If $A,B$ are mutually exclusive, and if $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are both positive, then $A,B$ _cannot_ be independent, since we would have $P(A\cap B)=0$, but $P(A)P(B) > 0$.